# How to organise a list of coordinates for closest distance using python?

Tags: python

This is the list of points:

```
points = [(2.8, 9.8), (0.3, 8.3), (4.4, 8.8), (6.8, 7.4), (4.1, 0.3), (4.5, 0.0), (7.6, 1.1), (5.0, 8.2), (7.7, 1.8), (3.4, 6.9), (4.8, 3.2), (0.7, 7.9)]
path = best_path(points)
print(path)
```

and this is what I have so far, but it doesn't return a list back...

```
def best_path(points):
  path=[]
  remaining_points=[]
  remaining_points.append(points)
  start = remaining_points[0]
  while len(remaining_points) > 0:
    processing = find_closest(start,remaining_points)
    path.append(processing)
    remaining_points.pop(processing)
    start = path(processing)
  return path
```

Comment: What would be the exact logic and expected output?

Comment: Also, where is `find_closest`?

Comment: Closest to what, each other? To some reference point? If you're looking to minimize the total distance to visit all points in the list you have rediscovered the [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) which is NP-hard.

Comment: @Boris Ryavkin you must specify what do you want the distance between

Comment: Are you trying to implement the Dijkstra algorithm ? Asking because of how you named your function "best_path". What is the start point of your path ? Do you need to go through all points ? If you can add a working example it's better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna assume you want to calculate distance from every point to a single point, let's call it `my_loc = (0, 0)`

#### Step 1.

Iterate through all the points and calculate their distance using a^2 = b^2 + c^2 pythagorean theorem:

```py
def dist(loc_a, loc_b):
    x1, x2 = loc_a[0], loc_b[0]
    y1, y2 = loc_a[1], loc_b[1]
    z = ((x2-x1) ** 2) + ((y2-y1) ** 2)
    return z ** (1/2)
    # optionally embrace return value with round(float, decimal_points)
```

If I got anything wrong here, here's the formula:

[image: formula]
where
*|AB|* is the distance between 2 points, and `x` and `y` components are coordinates of a point *A* and *B*.

#### Step 2.

Save all your distances by order to a list, so you will have

```py
points = [(2.8, 9.8), (0.3, 8.3), (4.4, 8.8), (6.8, 7.4), (4.1, 0.3), (4.5, 0.0), (7.6, 1.1), (5.0, 8.2), (7.7, 1.8), (3.4, 6.9), (4.8, 3.2), (0.7, 7.9)]
# and distances
distances = [10.192153844992728, 8.305419917138448, 9.838699100999076, 10.04987562112089, 4.110960958218893, 4.5, 7.679192665899196, 9.604165762834375, 7.907591289387686, 7.692203845452875, 5.768882040742383, 7.930952023559341]
```

where each element of both list shares the same index *(assumming all points are valid, that is [x, y])*

[*Code here*](https://pastebin.com/9PXCpvSm)